# Why does Puppet Agent refuse to use cached catalog when connection to master fails?

Tags: puppet

I am considering deploying Puppet to an unreliable network, and it is important that we have some desired state management occurring on the nodes even when the Puppet master is down or uncontactable.

I have been testing Puppet's cached catalog to see if that would be a solution, the idea being it would execute the cached catalog when the agent fails to connect to the server. However, rather than using the cached catalog, it just borks out and refuses to do anything:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Connection refused - connect(2)
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Yes, there is a config option called use_cached_catalog, which when set to true will cause the Agent to *only* use the cached catalog and *never* update its configuration from the master, which is definitely not what I want - as the whole point of this kind of system is we should be able to push new configurations to the nodes when they are eventually able to check in with the master.

There is also another option, usecacheonfailure, however this seems only to be triggered when the catalog fails to compile, not when the agent is simply unable to connect to the master. Or at least this option doesn't work for me.

This seems like a pretty obvious thing to be able to do, what a I missing here?

```
# puppet --version
3.5.1
# facter --version
2.0.1
```

CentOS 6.5.

And yes, I know about masterless puppet, however I don't want to go down that path just yet as there is a lot of value in having a central server that can report on the status of all the nodes, and not having to set up a different file syncing mechanism.

Comment: what does the puppet.conf look like?

Comment: Not sure if this is intended behavior. I suggest you look for a bug report about this, that may shed some light on the design decision. If there is no bug, you should report this.